# Is there a better way to add a property of an array of objects to another array than a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that all have a property called `Id`, laid out similarly to this:

```
var allPeople = [ { 'id': someNumber, 'name': someString }, { 'id': anotherNumber, 'name': anotherString }, ... ]
```

I want to grab each of the id's and concatenate them on to another array, which I will call `selectedPeople`:

```
[ someNumber, AnotherNumber ]
```

Currently, I'm using a `for` loop to push each id onto the `selectedPeople` array:

```
 for (i = 0; i < allPeople.length; i++) {
      selectedPeople.push(allPeople[i].id);
 }
```

However, this feels rather procedural, and I'm wondering whether there's a better way of approaching this? Does Javascript have a method which can fulfill what I want to achieve?

Comment: For what's it's worth I'd use a for loop to do it

Comment: Is your data originally coming from JSON? If so, then you can build the secondary array while it's being parsed so you don't need a second loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
    var allPeople = [{
      'id': someNumber,
      'name': someString
    }, {
      'id': anotherNumber,
      'name': anotherString
    }, ...]
    var selectedPeople = allPeople.map(function(person) {
      return person.id
    });
    console.log(selectedPeople);
```

Comment: I was not aware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` array method to transform the array

something like:

```
var allPeople = [ { 'id': someNumber, 'name': someString }, { 'id': anotherNumber, 'name': anotherString }]

var ids = allPeople.map(function(person) {return person.id;});
//ids is [someNumber, AnotherNumber ]
```

Comment: "command" isn't a meaningful term in JavaScript - `map` is a function or a method of `Array.prototype`.